# Build Error in Android Studio 2.1.3

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build, emulation

I am using android studio 2.1.3. I am getting the following error, in spite of clearing the project and rebuilding it again, restarting etc... How to solve it?

> Error:Execution failed for task :app:transformClassesWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDebug.
>
> org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.DescriptiveChange cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.InputFileDetails
> ay be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
> Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
>
> The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
> Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
>
> Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks.

I am using Windows 8.1
I tried deleting the folder .gradle in the application folder. Then I cleaned the project and build it again. IT WORKS FINE NOW.

Comment: Thank you. this solved the problem for me too. You should select your answer as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

- Have you cleaned your project through terminal ?
  If not use `./gradlew clean` this from root project.
- Also check your gradle files, Is everything is up-to-date and correctly written there. Check for dependencies also.