# Execution failed for task transformClassesWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDebug when i run project in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have an error when I am running my project in android studio.
It's error log form gradle Console

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDebug'.
>   org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.DescriptiveChange cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.InputFileDetails
> - Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

This error is only when I am running my project, when I am using Clear Project or Rebuild Project everything is ok. Had someone a similar problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39113787/build-error-in-android-studio-2-1-3

Comment: Without results. When I rebuilding project everything is ok. But run has an error. I did what was in that link

Answer (score 0):

Try to Clean project or  Rebuild project.
`Build Menu` > `Clean Project` and `Build Menu` > `Rebuild Project`