# Gradle Error : com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDependencyCheckerForDebug'.

> org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.DescriptiveChange cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.InputFileDetails
>   he may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
>   Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
>
> The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
>   Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
>
> Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
>
> Information:BUILD FAILED
>
> Information:Total time: 1 mins 21.644 secs Information:1 error

My **build.gradle** dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
    compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

## ALREADY TRIED:

This Solution:

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    preDexLibraries = false
}
```

This Solution:

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

and CLEAN, INVALIDATE and RESTART, all option tried but didn't found any solution.

Is there any help please?

Comment: maybe try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39113787/build-error-in-android-studio-2-1-3 ?

Answer (score 1):

This happened with me just a few hours ago when I opened an old project after few months.
Problem with me was that as I have updated Android Studio after that so gradle plugin too need to be updated. But as soon as I changed gradle version it start giving me this error.

To solve this, I did following steps

**1.** Change your distribution url in `gradle-wrapper.properties` file.

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.2.1-all.zip

**2.** Delete caches from your system **Users/.gradle** folder

**3.** Rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing same issue there.

I deleted the .gradle folder under C:\Users(user-name).gradle

rerun

```
cordova build android
```

and it worked.

I dont know it can happened, but I think some files or configuration has corrupted on gradle.